# function download in CakePHP 1.2 - vCard file

Tags: php, function, cakephp, mime-types

I'm doing some simple content maintenance on a site built on CakePHP 1.2. I did not develop the site. I'm unable to set up a localhost instance of the site because the framework is ancient, and I'm a hack. Consequently, I'm unable to test before deployment. Not a best case scenario, but it is what it is.

The text content updates are complete. However, the client has requested that a .vcf file be linked to for download from a static .thtml file.

My first attempt to implement this saw plain text returned when the **a href** was clicked.

In consulting the 1.2 manual I see there's a Media Views function:

```
function download () {
    $this->view = 'Media';
    $params = array(
          'id' => 'example.zip',
          'name' => 'example',
          'download' => true,
          'extension' => 'zip',
          'path' => APP . 'files' . DS
   );
   $this->set($params);
}
```

which I have mod'd thus:

```
function download () {
    $this->view = 'Media';
    $params = array(
          'id' => 'emp-name.vcf',
          'name' => 'emp-name',
          'download' => true,
          'extension' => '.vcf',
          'path' => APP . '/webroot/files' . DS
   );
   $this->set($params);
}
```

Can someone confirm that I'm heading in the right direction with this by adding this function to /app/controllers/pages_controller.php

As I say, I'm unable to test before deployment, and am concerned about breakage. Yes, I'm making .baks to fall back on.

tia

---

**update:**

Pushed /app/controller/pages_controller.php live.

Nothing broke, but the .vcf still displays as text when the link is clicked.

Maybe this controller isn't affecting the page: /app/views/pages/contact.thtml ?

Comment: Two things: you may remove the dot before "vcf" in the extension parameter, and remove the slash before "webroot", because if in the original example is absent, it seems that APP constant already have a final slash.

Comment: quite right, thanks for the catch.

Comment: I've read the edit. Well, this opens a new world that is not CakePHP based. When you open a file via direct URL in your browser, it follows its default behaviour for that MIME-type. Maybe there is something wrong with the header sent by PHP to encourage browser to download the file, or maybe your browser is configured to show .vcf as plain-text. Try to add mimeType to your $params array, setting its value to "text/x-vcard". In each case, check in your browser dev console if in the server response the header "Content-disposition" is set to "attachment". Check the behaviour for each browser.